# Android 13 : Getting Android.App.Result.Canceled on OnActivityresult when Taking Picture from Camera

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-internal-storage

Team,

Trying to Work on Camera Taking Picture but everytime getting result as Android.App.Result.Canceled and data as null on OnActivityresult function.

```
TakePicture.Click += delegate
        {
            if (slabDetails != null)
            {
                File SlabFile = new File(Constants.INVENTORY_PATH, slabDetails.ExtSlabNo + ".jpg");
                //if (SlabFile.Exists()) { SlabFile.Delete(); }
                //SlabFile.CreateNewFile();
                imageUri = Uri.FromFile(SlabFile);

                //var documentsDirectry = ApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
                //File cameraFile = new Java.IO.File(documentsDirectry, "default_image" + ".jpg");
                //Uri photoURI = Uri.FromFile(cameraFile);

                Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                camIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
                camIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, imageUri);
                camIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                camIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
                StartActivityForResult(camIntent, 2);
            }
        };
```

On Activity Result Function

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 2:// From Camera
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        new SyncDataTask(this, data, 1, db).Execute();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
                        var methodName = method.Name;
                        var className = method.ReflectedType.Name;

                        MainActivity.SaveLogReport(className, methodName, ex);
                    }
                    catch (OutOfMemoryError ex)
                    {
                        ex.PrintStackTrace();
                    } 
               }
         }
   }
```

Using Xamarin Native Android deploying in Android API 33 and Android 12 Version tablets. It Return the Image and Works good on android version 11 tablets.

Provided permissions in android manifest file as per Android 13 Tutorials

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So, I would like to return Android.App.Result.Ok and data in ActivityResult. So, Do anybody faced the issue. Please help me in this Case. Thanks in  Advance.

Comment: `SlabFile.CreateNewFile();` Do not create an empty file already. As if the user cancels the picture you end up with an empty file.

Comment: @blackapps, Thank you for the response. Commented the line, didn't create the empty file, still getting Android.App.Result.Canceled and data as null on ActivityResult function      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

Comment: Where in your code is that Canceled? I dont see it. And which data are you talking about? Can you talk about resultCode parameter?

Comment: @blackapps, Yes, (Result resultCode) is getting as Android.App.Result.Cancelled and (Intent  data) is getting null eventhough i capture photo. It works good on android 11 and after upgrade to Android 12/13 am facing the issue. see my edited question

Comment: @blackapps,  Can you help on this.

Comment: @Prescott Chartier,  I am facing the same issue as you faced. Can you help me in this regard

Comment: It might be related to the [does not work with Android 13 Android.permission.write_external_storage](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11275)